# How to Access JSON Object Properties as table in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am new in Angular 2 and trying to access data from API. As Output, I am getting API response on my browser as all JSON objects. But I don't know how to access the individual properties. below is my code:

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpTestService } from './http-test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'http-test',
  templateUrl: './http-test.component.html',
  providers: [HttpTestService]

})
export class HttpTestComponent implements OnInit {

  getData:string;
  postData: string;

  constructor(private _httpService: HttpTestService) { }

  getTest(){
    this._httpService.getData()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data) 
        );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTestService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }  

  getData(){
        return this._http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .map(res => res.json())
  }

}
```

**test.component.html**

In this file, when I use `{{getdata}}` I get whole JSON object, but when I try to access any of its property I get ERROR

```
<button (click)="getTest()">Get Result</button>
output: 
<ul>
<li>{{ getData[0][time] }}</li>
</ul>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpTestComponent } from './http-test/http-test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HttpTestComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {  }
```

**Output: **
[image: This is my output, and I want to access its individual property (like..email) as list]

Comment: create an interface and bind the properties and display in table form as we do in angular1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.getData = JSON.stringify(data)`  will make your object a string and you can't reach a strings fields like an object. Remove it.

Then you need to reach to `time` key as a "string"

Try:

```
<li>{{ getData[0]['time'] }}</li>
```

or

```
<li>{{ getData[0]?.time }}</li>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CB3oGppm4fvoEExfDSRc?p=preview

Comment: I tried it, and having an error _Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter_

Comment: @vinayofficial I've just seen that you are stringifying your object `this.getData = JSON.stringify(data)` remove it.

Comment: I changed my statement to _data => this.getData_ and in html view _<li>{{ getData[0]?.time }}</li>_ but still having error.

Comment: Errror is *Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js:259
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:242
onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:269
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:241
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:535
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:260
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:274
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:433
*

Comment: @vinayofficial I've updated the plunker example with the link you provided. I managed to get the object from the url but there is no time field in the first key's value.. Check the log for the full object. I don't know why do you get the stack error tho, you must be doing something wrong elsewhere. Maybe you are not initializing the getData object like `getData:any = {};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133350/discussion-between-vinayofficial-and-echonax).

Answer (score 3):

Change Your code in plunker as shown below :

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ConfigurationService } from './ConfigurationService';


    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `

        <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of getData">
          <td>{{data.address.street}}</td>
          <td>{{data.address.geo.lat}}</td>
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      `
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      getData : any[] ;

       constructor(private _ConfigurationService: ConfigurationService)
        {
            console.log("Reading _ConfigurationService ");
            //console.log(_ConfigurationService.getConfiguration());

             this._ConfigurationService.getConfiguration()
                .subscribe(
                (data)=> {
                    this.getData = data; 
                    console.log(this.getData);
                },
                (error) => console.log("error : " + error)
            );

        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. WORKING !!

Comment: I am getting an error _can not find name any_ at `getData : any[];`

Comment: try getData; only